# Check if one file has changed and another hasn't using grep for Git pre-commit

Tags: bash, git, grep

I want to check if my schema.graphqls has been changed in a commit, if it has and my generated.go hasn't changed I want to reject the commit. Currently my pre-commit hook is the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
GENERATED_FILE="graphql/generated/generated.go"
SCHEMA_FILE="graphql/schema.graphqls"
git diff --cached --name-only | if grep -E "$SCHEMA_FILE" | grep -E invert "$GENERATED_FILE"
then
    echo "Schema file has changed and generated code needs updating."
  exit 1
fi
```

It's currently allowing me to commit even if just the schema.graphqls has changed and not my generated.go. I'm not sure if it's the AND I'm attempting with grep.

Comment: This is a reasonable (or not-entirely-un-reasonable at least) approach, but if your go file is generated from your schema file, I'd suggest not committing the go file at all.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff --quiet <file>` returns `1` if `<file>` has changed and `0` if not, allowing you do to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
GENERATED_FILE="graphql/generated/generated.go"
SCHEMA_FILE="graphql/schema.graphqls"
if ! git diff-index --cached HEAD --quiet "${SCHEMA_FILE}" &&\
     git diff-index --cached HEAD --quiet "${GENERATED_FILE}"
then
    echo "Schema file has changed and generated code needs updating."
    exit 1
fi
```

(Remember that `0` is `true` and everything else is `false` in Bash.)

---

**Edit**: Incorporated torek's corrections.

Comment: This doesn't seem to recognise when a file hasn't changed.

Comment: This is close, but you want to use `git diff --cached` so as to compare the index copy of the file to the `HEAD` commit copy of the file. Or, perhaps better, `git diff-index --cached HEAD`. (Keep the `--quiet` and file names to use this method.)